# Slow PyMongo Bulk UpdateMany Performance

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

What's the best way to update one field within multiple hundreds of thousands of documents based on a unique identifier which appears within multiple documents (usually thousands)?

A brief example of the scenario:

Each document contains a non-unique field called IP, and the aim is to update each document based on a given IP with metadata. E.g. the IP '127.0.0.1' could be associated with 22,000 thousand documents within MongoDB, each of which is required to be updated with the same metadata. This process continues for all IP addresses, and subsequently, all multiple hundreds of thousands of documents. My current approach to this utilises the bulk_write and UpdateMany operation within PyMongo. However, this approach takes multiple tens of hours to complete the task successfully. Is there a more efficient way of achieving what I am after?

A snippet of my current logic (the and query operator is required as the data is time-sensitive):

```
bulk_updates = []

for ip in ips:
    bulk_updates.append(UpdateMany({"$and": [{"ip": ip}, {'timestamp': timestamp}]}, {'$set': {'metadata': meta}}))

mainDB[db_name].bulk_write(bulk_updates)
```

Any help/suggestion to improve the performance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Figure out whether you want to optimize the finds or the writes.

Comment: @D.SM Thanks for the response. Any chance you would be able to point me in the right direction on how to improve either of these aspects? What do you feel would be easier in this scenario? Optimising the finds I assume?

Comment: You can start by reading basic query optimization guides. Replace find-and-replaces with simple finds, time them, look at query plans.